# How to sort from higher to smaller value in foreach by using PHP?

Tags: php

I've generate a range of date from last months by using Foreach in PHP it worked ask well But I want to sort it from highest value to smaller than.

```
<?php
$begin = new DateTime('2015-11-01');
$end = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
$i = 1;
foreach ($daterange as $in => $val) {

      $tr = '<tr>' .
            '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $val->format("Y-m-d") . ' 13:00' . '</td>' .
            '</tr>';
     echo $tr;
     $tr =  '<tr>' .
            '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $val->format("Y-m-d") . ' 18:00' . '</td>' .
            '</tr>';
     echo $tr;
 }
?>
```

Below is my result

```
1   2015-11-01 13:00
2   2015-11-01 18:00
3   2015-11-02 13:00
4   2015-11-02 18:00
5   2015-11-03 13:00
```

But But I want like this

```
1   2015-11-03 13:00
2   2015-11-03 18:00
3   2015-11-02 13:00
4   2015-11-02 18:00
5   2015-11-01 13:00
6   2015-11-01 18:00
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried to swap `$begin` and `$end` and set a negative interval ?

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` is not the right tool in this case.
You should use `while` and `Date::sub(interval)`:

```
$i = 1;
echo "<table>";
$current = clone $end;
while( ($val = $current) >= $begin) {
    $tr = '<tr>' .
        '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $val->format("Y-m-d") . ' 13:00' . '</td>' .
        '</tr>';
    echo $tr;
    $tr =  '<tr>' .
        '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $val->format("Y-m-d") . ' 18:00' . '</td>' .
        '</tr>';
    echo $tr;
    $current->sub($interval);
}
```

Comment: @ chumkiu

Why Foreach is not right to use for this cause Please help to expland me

Comment: @HengSopheak simply because you have no control of selector. Foreach is for reading a traversable object from begin to end. That's the opposite that you want

Comment: OH yes i understand what you mean but I will used some selector after I build this function

Answer (score 1):

You can use what is known as bubble sort : have a look on the code below, it sorts from max to min

```
function bubble_sort($arr) {
    $size = count($arr);
    for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {
            if ($arr[$j+1] > $arr[$j]) {
                swap($arr, $j, $j+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
    $tmp = $arr[$a];
    $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
    $arr[$b] = $tmp;
}

/* test bubble sort */

$arr = array(31,3,2,55,15,7,4,90);

print("Before sorting");
print_r($arr);

$arr = bubble_sort($arr);
echo "<br/>";
print("After sorting by using bubble sort");
echo "<br/>";
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess that `new DatePeriod()` returns its result already sorted. Looks like you want it backwards, if I understood your question correctly. With PHP's `array_reverse`, you can reverse an array. Placing the following line in front of your `foreach`-loop should give you the result you want:

```
$daterange = array_reverse($daterange);
```

Comment: Message: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: What's the type of `$daterange`? I thought it would be array or object since you are passing it to the `foreach`..

Comment: it's an object. And objects do not behave as array's (there are some exceptions though)